# How to create a cron job in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm creating a simple cron job that run a task in a specific time (for example 3AM) with Play Framework 2.6.x.
But now I'm stucking in a simple schedule task:

I created an Actor:

```
package actors;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DoSomethingActor extends UntypedActor {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DoSomethingActor.class);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Object message) throws Throwable {
        log.info("Write your crone task or simply call your method here that perform your task " + message);

    }

}
```

Then I created a Schedule class that call Actor each time I've set:

```
package tasks;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Cancellable;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

@Singleton
public class DoSomethingScheduler {

    @Inject
    public DoSomethingScheduler(final ActorSystem system,
            @Named("do-something-actor") final ActorRef doSomethingActor) {
        final Cancellable scheduler;
        final int timeDelayFromAppStart = 0;
        final int timeGapInSeconds = 1; //Here you provide the time delay for every run
        system.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(timeDelayFromAppStart, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay when system start
                Duration.create(timeGapInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS),     //Frequency delay for next run
                doSomethingActor,
                "message for onreceive method of doSomethingActor",
                system.dispatcher(),
                null);
    }
}
```

Finally, I bind these class in a Module class:

```
package modules;

import actors.DoSomethingActor;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

import play.libs.akka.AkkaGuiceSupport;
import tasks.DoSomethingScheduler;

public class SchedulerModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        this.bindActor(DoSomethingActor.class, "do-something-actor");
        this.bind(DoSomethingScheduler.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

After these things, I run the application but it doesn't work as I expected. I expected it shows a logging every 1 SECOND but there is nothing happen.

Could you please help me to fix it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you add the module to your configuration?

Comment: Yes, I added `play.modules.enabled += "modules.SchedulerModule"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in dev mode, I have to send a HTTP request to the application to load the module. In production mode, they will be loaded immediately.